# Laravel backpack on production

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm building a small website for a collage homework and I'm using **Backpack OPEN CORE** pricing plan (the free one)

Can I use my website on the *on production server* with **Backpack OPEN CORE** plan or do I need to buy a license code?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Backpack v5’s core is free and open source (MIT License) - so yes, you can build anything you want with it, no strings attached.

No need to buy anything, if you don’t need any of the PRO features.